# How do I call a child method using the parent object in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I want to call child method using parent object in javascript how can I do it?

```
var Shape = function () { }
    Shape.prototype.draw = function () {
        return "Generic shape called ";
    }

    var Circle = function () { }
    Circle.prototype = Object.create(Shape.prototype);
    Circle.prototype.draw = function () {
        return "I am from Circle";
    }

    var Rectangle = function () { }
    Rectangle.prototype = Object.create(Shape.prototype);
    Rectangle.prototype.draw = function () {
        return "I am from Rectangle";
    }

    var Triangle = function () { }
    Triangle.prototype = Object.create(Shape.prototype);
```

I want to access any overridden method like Rectangle, Circle any one but using Shape object like in c# what we can do: Shape shape=new Circle() shape.draw(); it will call overridden method of the child class.I want to do the same thing in javascript how can I achieve it

Comment: "calling child method using parent object" doesn't sound quite OO. In your example I also don't see which method you're trying to call?

Comment: What exactly do you want to do? Which child method? Which parent method?

Comment: i want to access any overridden method like Rectangle ,Cirlce any one but using Shape object like in c# what we can do : Shape shape=new Circle()
shape.draw(); it will call overriden method of child class .I want to do same thing in java script how can i achieve it .

Comment: Pretty much the same way. If you instantiate a `Circle` and it defines a `draw` method on its prototype, then `circleInstance.draw()` calls that method.

Answer (score 1):

```js
var Shape = function () { }
    Shape.prototype.draw = function () {
        return "Generic shape called ";
    }
    Shape.prototype.val = 10;

    var Circle = function () { }
    Circle.prototype = Object.create(Shape.prototype);
    Circle.prototype.draw = function () {
        return "I am from Cirlce";
    }

    var Rectangle = function () { }
    Rectangle.prototype = Object.create(Shape.prototype);
    Rectangle.prototype.draw = function () {
        return "I am from Rectangle";
    }

    var Triangle = function () { }
    Triangle.prototype = Object.create(Shape.prototype);
    Triangle.prototype.draw = function () {
        return "I am from Triangle";
    }
        
    //Using Up casting (access value of parent object)
    var newCircle = new Circle();
    alert("newCircle: "+newCircle.draw()+" : "+newCircle.val);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using any subclass of `Shape` in your code ( you can check at runtime with `instanceof` operator) you can simple invoke the method. Js runtime would automatically call the right method from the prototype chain. So, if you have an object in code called `myshape`, you can:

`if(myshape instanceof Shape){`

```
    // invoke draw method
   myshape.draw();
}
```